# Django: dynamic changing email recepients

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I making a feedback form on website. I made model called 'globalapp' with all settings for future admin, it have email,address and phone fields without permissions for add or delete this objects.

In my views i have a simple code:

```
def index(request):
    seos = SEO.objects.get(id__exact=1)
    socs = Social_networks.objects.get(id__exact=1)
    globs = globalapp.objects.get(id__exact=1)
    index = Index.objects.get(id__exact=1)

    form = ContactForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        fille = form.cleaned_data['fille']
        recepients = ['test@test.ru']

        from_email, to =  sender, recepients

        html_content = loader.render_to_string('globalapp/chunks/email_tpl.html',
    {'subject': subject, 'sender':sender, 'message':message, 'fille':fille})

        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html_content, from_email, to)
        msg.send()

    return render(request, 'globalapp/index.html', {'seos': seos, 
                                                   'socs': socs,
                                                   'globs': globs,
                                                   'index': index,
                                                   'form': form })
```

Right now mail sending on test@test.ru. I want to take email field from globalapp object, and put it in 'recepients', to give admin ability to change email address when he needs it.

The best thing that i get yet, i get email value by queryset with:

```
email = globalapp.objects.filter(id=1).values('email')
```

by in mail ive got only `To: {'email': 'test@gmail.com'}`

So question is how to get string from queryset object for dynamic email recepients changing? Or maybe i have option how to do it other way?

Also i have another little problem, that i cant deal with yet: after i push submit button, my page reloading, and i dont need it, can i disable it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are two problems here:

1. you use `.filter(..)`, and a filter means you do not get a *single* dictionary, but a `QuerySet` of dictionaries. This can be empty, contain one, or multiple elements. Since you filter on `id=...`, it will contan *at most* one element, but still it will require some extra logic to unwrap it out of the `QuerySet`, so we better use `.get(..)` here; and
2. we obtain a dictionary, we can retrieve the element associated with the key, by performing an *element lookup*, so `the_dict['email']`.

We can tus obtain the email address with:

```
email = globalapp.objects.values('email').get(id=1)['email']
```

Or perhaps more elegant:

```
email = globalapp.objects.values_list('email', flat=True).get(id=1)
```

> Also i have another little problem, that i cant deal with yet: after i push submit button, my page reloading, and i dont need it, can i disable it somehow?

Not with a form, since that is exactly the task the browser is supposed to carry out: send a HTTP request, and load the response. But you can use an AJAX call to perform a HTTP request while the webpage still remains the same.